# jQuery / Ajax - request coming back as error

Tags: jquery, ajax, magento

Im trying to get the email from the url below, but for example if I go to the url in the browser it returns `{"customer_email": "email@email.com" }` but the ajax request below always returns as an error - is there something I am doing wrong?

```
var url = window.location.host + "/emarsys/ajax/getLoggedInCustomerEmail/?isAjax=1";

jQuery.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (result) {
        console.log('success');
    },
    error: function () {
        console.log('error');
    }
});


class Emarsys_AjaxController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {

public function getLoggedInCustomerEmailAction(){
    $response = ['customer_email' => ''];
    $customerSession = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
    if (Mage::app()->getRequest()->isAjax() && $customerSession->getCustomerId()) {
        $response['customer_email'] = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getEmail();
    }

    $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response));
}
}
```

Comment: can we see PHP or whatever lang it is code?

Comment: it can be caused by a few things, not sure what language your backebd is, but just for example, let's use PHP - it can be caused if var_dump's and print_r's are littered through your script, ajax only returns success with echos

Comment: yep its PHP i've just added the controller if that helps?

Answer (score 0):

I checked the network tab and it was returning 404 as the url was doubling itself so I changed it to just: `url: "/emarsys/ajax/getLoggedInCustomerEmail/?isAjax=1",` which fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Try this
var url = window.origin + "/emarsys/ajax/getLoggedInCustomerEmail/?isAjax=1";